# How can I make a ListView with custom color with both mouse and keyboard navigation in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I work on WPF/C# application. A part of this application is a WPF ListView that support navigation by mouse and keyboard. How can I make this work with a custom background colors for displaying that and list item is active/selcted? I would like a solution based on XAML with mininal C#.

I have tried making "manual" styling from code behind, by adding setters to the item style. It seems like this strategy is messing things up. I end up getting only default WPF styling
I have searched a lot on the internet and stack overflow but could not find anything specific about styling WPF listview with keyboard navigation

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- This styling does not work. Should it be changed? -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown"/>                    
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"
              PreviewKeyDown="listView_PreviewKeyDown"
              SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem>A</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>B</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>C</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(listView, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
}

public void listView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var item = GetListViewItemOnIndex(listView, i);
        if (item.IsFocused) { /* Set selected style? */ }
        else { /* Set transparent style? */ }
    }
}

private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var item = GetListViewItemOnIndex(listView, i);
        if (item.IsFocused) { /* Set selected style? */ }
        else { /* Set transparent style? */ }
    }
}

private ListViewItem GetListViewItemOnIndex(ListView listView, int index)
{
    return listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
}
```

Comment: I guess you are new to WPF development. Try reading about Binding, the way the code is written is not the best way for a WPF code. You need to start reading about property binding. If a ui control/style is bound to a property, you can change it in the code behind and it will start reflecting it. To do that, you need to understand the basics of property binding and INotifyPropertyChanged interface. No one will be able to fix this code, as it needs a full re-write.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. The ListViewItem Style just works and changes the Background property when the mouse is over the item. If you are however asking about focus and selection, that's more complex. Since it's a bit easier, I'd recommend to use ListBox instead of ListView, and take a look at [ListBox Styles and Templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates) to get an idea how the different states of a ListBoxItem are actually visualized. And please kindly ignore the previous comment. Your problem is not related to data binding.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. I have also not having much trouble with the mouseover and selection by mouse. My main trouble is related to keyboard selection. Not the actual navigation and selection but setting and maintaining a style (like mouse over just for keyboard) that is different than the deafult WPF styling.

I will have a look at ListBox